# (Asking for a friend) "The December's"

Tags: grammar

Which of these is correct:

"The December's 1st update" 
Or
"December's first update" or "The December 1st update"

The update will happen on December 1st. My friend insists that the first option is correct but I am having a hard time explaining why it isn't, can I get some help please

Comment: Only use *1st* if you're talking about a date; if you're talking about something that's never happened before use *first*. The question isn't at all clear because it's not comparing the same thing. Is it talking about an update that happens on 12/1 or it it talking about the initial instance of an update that could happen at any time of the month?

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! It's an update that will happen on December 1st, my apologies

Comment: "December's first update" could mean that it is the first of several updates scheduled for the month of December. Say "December 1 update" or "The update of December 1".

Comment: The intended meaning aside, all of those versions are actually grammatical. The first is unusual (***the*** would normally be dropped from the possessive form), but if it's a specific December, the definite article *could* be appropriate in the right context.